# Check if a Differential operator is self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with boundary of class $C^2$. Define
\begin{cases}
D(A) = H^2 \cap H_0^1(\Omega;\mathbb{C})\\
Au(x)=\Delta u(x)-V(x)u(x) \hspace{3mm} x \in \Omega \hspace{2mm}\mbox{a.e.}
\end{cases}

where we assume that $V \in L^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$. I must show that $A$ is self-adjoint in $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C})$.

First I would like to check that $A$ is symmetric and my idea was integrating by parts and then see that $\rho (A) \cap \mathbb{R} \neq \emptyset$. But how to do deal with integration by parts when I have Laplacian?

Comment: $$\int g(\Delta f) = \textrm{Boundary terms}-\int {\nabla g}\cdot \nabla f$$

Comment: I think in you case you even have $\int g (\Delta f) = \int (\Delta g) f$, at least for $g\in H^2 \cap C^\infty_{\text{cpt}}(\Omega,\mathbb{C})$ very much by definition of the weak Laplace. I think the general case should/could/might follow by density.